# How ConcurrentSkipListMap provides synchronization?

Tags: java, collections, synchronization, concurrentskiplistmap

I'm quite confused how ConcurrentSkipListMap provides synchronization. 
I can find no synchronized blocks in the source code and no article or question about how it happens to be synchronized.

Comment: Don't know the specifics, but with a cursory look at the implementation in Java 14 I can see multiple uses of the [`VarHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) API, including `#acquireFence()`, `#releaseFence()`, `#fullFence()`, and `#compareAndSet(Object...)`.

Comment: It doesn’t provide synchronization. That’s what the `Concurrent…` in its class name suggests, no synchronization. You may be concerned about [Memory Visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), which can be achieved in more ways than synchronized blocks.

Comment: Yeah. Got it, the problem is, that I'm not familiar with that concepts and was looking for familiar keywords in source code and I actually found them in other implementations ConcurrentHashMap, CopyOnWriteArrayList, but not here. There is much to learn. Thank you!